# Correlation between daily average and individual observations

Tags: regression, correlation, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I just want to calculate the correlation between two variables. One of them ($Y$) is measured daily while the other ($X$) is measured multiple times per day. The two obvious options are:

1. Calculate the correlation between $Y$ and the daily average of $X$
2. Broadcast the value of $Y$ for each value of $X$ on a given day and calculate the correlation.

Obviously this question applies to regression more broadly, but all I really want is to calculate the correlation.

It doesn't seem like multi-level models are exactly what I want, because I think they assume the effect of $X$ on $Y$ differs by group. In my case, the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multilevel analyses do not assume that effects are fixed, they can be specified as fixed or random, but it is up to you to choose.

I would regress $X$ on $Y$ and adding days as clusters. The nice thing about multilevel analysis is that it weights the effects of days. For example, consider two scenarios, you could either (a) pool your data per day (average by day), or (b) ignore day and put all data in a single regression. In (a) you lose the within day variation and in (b) you are mixing within and between day variation altogether. The multilevel analysis will weight between these two scenarios.

Comment: This would be better than averaging all X within a day because that approach would not account for possibly different numbers of X's on different days. How would they estimate the correlation after fitting that model?